# Type 'HttpEvent<name[]> is not assignable to type 'name[]'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

this is my code:

```
export interface act {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

```
public list!: act[];
```

```
getAll(token:any): void{
  this.http.get<act[]>('http://localhost:4200/test', token)
  .subscribe(
    (val) =>
      this.list = val
  );
}
```

And I'm getting the following error on `this.list = val`:

> Type 'HttpEvent < act[] >' is not assignable to type 'act[]'. Type 'HttpSentEvent' is missing the following properties from type 'act[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 16 more.

I tried searching on google, reading on stack but had no luck. I found similar questions but some are not solved and others are different.

Hope you can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the type of `val`?

Comment: What is `token` supposed to be? Don't use the `any` type, and everything will be more understandable, for you and for the compiler.

Comment: val type should be act[]. Token is a json but it doesn't affect the question, I will remove it to prevent confusion.

Comment: token very much affects the question. It's its presence that causes this compilation error. Your edited code won't have the error anymore.

Comment: hmm then I didn't understand httpClient docs. Token is supposed to be a json object passed in the body of the get.

Comment: GET requests don't have a body. The second argument of get() is not the body. It's a set of options affecting what the method is returning (among other things). If you need to send something in the body, then you should use post or put.

Comment: can you post that as answer? So I can upvote it. I will revert the edit. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to send a request body, but GET requests don't have a body. The second argument of `HttpClient.get()` is not the body, it's a set of options affecting, among other things, what the method returns.

So you should use POST or PUT instead of GET.

And you should also avoid using the `any` type, to make everything more understandable for you and for the compiler (which would have provided a more focused error message if you had used a properly defined interface instead of `any`).